# I do not take the "Custom Format Expression" defined

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I am making a report in which I am passing it as a string parameter, to be able to define some text box of a table with the = Format (Fields! Field.Value, "#.## 0,00"), but not achievement get that format.
Probe exchanging the separators, both thousands and decimals ("#, ## 0.00") and it ends up showing me the previously searched format, that is, the point as a thousand separator and the comma as a decimal separator.
What is happening to me?
When I define it "#. ## 0.00" do not type it and when I define it "#, ## 0.00" I type it but changing the separators (Ex: "1,298.57") ??

Both the report and the text box have already defined the "es-AR" language, which corresponds to the thousands separator with the period and the decimal separator with the comma.

Comment: Someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upload the answer since I did not take into account the Microsoft documentation. It implicitly indicates that the function expression "= Format" (Custom format) will only interpret the "en-US" format for decimal and thousands separators; and then apply the regional configuration from where it was executed from behind. I leave the Links:

- [Format – Text Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dax/format-function-dax)
- [Custom numeric formats for the FORMAT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function)
- [Formatting Numbers and Dates (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-numbers-and-dates-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

Regards!!